# Website return an error in iPhone version 2.0.1

Tags: javascript, html, ios, iphone, xml

My website is properly working on all  of the android versions and latest iPhone versions. But it is return an error ("A problem repeatedly occurred on 'http://www.mywebsite.com'") in IOS version 2.0.1. I have no idea about how fix the issue. please help me.

Comment: are you added the Transport security in your app

Comment: @Anbu.karthik No. I didn't. The website display the data from XML database. website loading time is 4s.

Comment: 2.0.1 or 12.0.1?

Comment: @Paulw11 it is IOS 2.0.1

Comment: Where did you even find a 10 year old iPhone to test on? Are people using 10 year old operating systems a major part of your user base?

Comment: @Paulw11 Because of my client use that crazy iPhone.

Comment: You will need to show some source code, but even then I doubt you will be able to get much help.  It could be as simple as Safari running out of memory if your web page is large. An original iPhone can be updated to iOS 3 and the 3GS can go to iOS 4.  2.0.1 isn't even the last version of iOS 2 that was released.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks. The problem is also happening in chrome and Firefox browsers.

Comment: Then you should probably try and use the debuggers on those browsers to see what is happening

Comment: @Paulw11 It is only that iPhone version. How to debug it?

Comment: What do you mean? You can't run chrome or Firefox on iOS 2; even if you could, those browsers are just wrappers to Safari on iOS. Are you 100% sure they don't mean 12.0.1; that is the current latest released version of iOS and is a much more reasonable platform to test on than 2.0.1 which was released in 2009

Comment: @Paulw11 Really. I didn't know. I think my client have some mistake. he said he use ios version 2.0.1

Comment: I would clarify. It is highly unlikely that they are one of the 3 people left in the world with a functioning original iPhone and that they are using it on a regular basis. You can use a safari debugger on iOS, but to do so you need to connect the iOS device to a Mac via a USB cable.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thank you. I really happy for your support. I felt crazy therefore that bug